# Error while using IMAPClient "ImportError : No module named imapclient"

Tags: pi-2, sendemail, pip

I have installed all Library as given here [Email Notifier StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39448/raspberry-pi-email-notifier-python-script-not-working/45872?noredirect=1#comment67858_45872)

Still I am getting error as:

```
"File "mail.py", 
line 1,in, import imapclient 
ImportError : No module named imapclient"
```

Please help I am new to Rpi.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sudo pip install imapclient
```